# Error in creating grouped bar chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I would like to create group bar chart using ggplot. Here is the sample data

```
> data
                            X0h     X3h     X6h     X9h    X12h
aldehyde_dehydrgenase   -0.7970 -0.7423 -0.5425 -0.6721 -0.6804
lactate_dehydrogenase    0.6737  0.5131  0.5063  0.4767  0.3628
aldehyde_reductase Akr1  0.4701  0.5694  0.2096  0.2696  0.2492

data <- read.csv("fig2.csv", header=T, row.names=1)
mat.melted <- melt(as.matrix(data), value.name = "expression", varnames=c('Enz', 'TimePoint'))

ggplot(mat.melted, aes(x=Enz, y=TimePoint, fill=expression)) +  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black')
```

This I got from the above
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVHPr.png)

The bars should be like as below (created using barplot function on same data)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBied.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gather() command within the tidyverse package can make this a bit easier. Tidyverse loads ggplot2 as well. See the code below. It appears to replicate your desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.csv("fig2.csv", header=T, row.names=1

### Melt the data using gather ###
graph <- data %>% 
  gather(hour, expression, -NameOfFirstColumn) %>% 
  arrange(name)

### Plot the data using ggplot2 ###
ggplot(graph, aes(x = name, y = expression, fill = hour)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: it gives error:  > graph <- data %>% 
+   gather(hour, expression, -name) %>% 
+   arrange(name)
Error in typeof(x) : object 'name' not found

Comment: ah that's because I named the first variable in your sample data "name." The sample data you provided above does not have a variable name for the first column, so I called it "name." Replace it with whatever you called the variable that contains aldehyde_dehydrgenase, etc.